# How to get the top 3 values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` which is as follows:

```
col1   col2             
aa     5      
bb     6          
cc     8        
dd     2      
ee     10
```

I want the output as a data frame which will contain the top 3 values (top 3 is calculated on the second column) of `df` like below:

```
col1   col2              
ee     10              
cc     8               
bb     6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `order` function in R for any sorting operations. For example in your case

```
df <- df[order(df$col2,decreasing = TRUE),]
```

This will give you an ordered dataframe based on second column. If you want top 3, just
select first 3 rows

```
df <- df[1:3,]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
head(df[rev(order(df$col2)),],3)
#    col1 col2
# 5   ee   10
# 3   cc    8
# 2   bb    6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
+ arrange(-col2) %>%
+ head(3)

  col1 col2
1   ee   10
2   cc    8
3   bb    6
```